# Kivy Python - passing an argument and tying kv and python files

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I am trying to tie a property of a python class (that inheres from a BoxLayout widget), and a kv profile of that class.

What  I am  trying to do is passing some value to the class, and print that value next to a kv file TextInput id (which is  the kv description of this class). When I ran my code I get an error:

```
TypeError: addBoxClass() missing 1 required positional argument: 'someNumber'
```

I think I over complicate things as this should be rather  simple.
Some bits of my code, I hope it is clear:

```
#at some point in my main code I call SomeClass    
box=SomeClass()
box.add_widget(SomeClass.addBoxClass(someNumber)) #someNumber is a value that I want to print in  def printInput, next to the kv file's TextInput id.

#then this is the class
class SomeClass(BoxLayout):
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super(NumOfRoomsClass, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    self.number = None

def addBoxClass(self,someNumber):        
    self.number = someNumber  #This is where I get my error
    #create and rern a label
    boxLabel = BoxLayout()        
    Lab = Label(text= self.number )
    boxLabel.add_widget(Lab )
    return (boxLabel)

def printInput(self, text):
    input= int(text)
    print ("self.number = ", self.number , "input = ",input) #This is what I'm aftre
```

and in my .kv file I`ve got this:

```
<SomeClass>:
    Label:
        text: "Number of rooms"

    TextInput:  
        multiline: False
        id: inputId 
        on_text_validate: root.printInput(inputId.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

As I looked at your code, I did not see where did you call the addBoxClass() function.

You created an instance of the SomeClass. Where:

```
self.number = None
```

And if you validate your textinput, it will call the printInput.
addBoxClass() is not called.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the someNumber that u are trying to call from your python file isn't define yet.

```
#at some point in my main code I call SomeClass    
box=SomeClass()
box.add_widget(SomeClass.addBoxClass(someNumber)) #someNumber is a value   that I want to print in  def printInput, next to the kv file's TextInput id.
```

should be

```
#at some point in my main code I call SomeClass 
someNumber  = 1
box=SomeClass()
box.add_widget(SomeClass.addBoxClass(someNumber)) #someNumber is a value that I want to print in  def printInput, next to the kv file's TextInput id.
```

someNumber must be given a value before you use it